# How can I run my spark app with python in the background with my computer shut off?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I always get this error message when I add deploy mode:

> Error: Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters.

```
dse spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 4G --total-executor-cores 2 \
  --driver-memory 1G \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.4.1 \
   --jars /root/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.4.1.jar \
   /root/pythonspark/com/spark/articles_axes.py weibo_article weibohao
```

Comment: Where are the workers? I think you need to use yarn for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example submit your application using detached [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session started on the same machine where you run Spark master:

```
screen -dmS spark dse spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 \
  --executor-memory 4G --total-executor-cores 2 \
  ...
```